# Time and Date for Javascript

Tags: javascript

how do I code the format Thu, Mar 4, 2021, 2:25 PM for time and date using Javascript. I tried using

```
  var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDay();
  var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var nameDay = daylist[day]; 
  var date = nameDay + "," + " " + (today.getMonth()+1) + " " + today.getDate() + "," + " " + today.getFullYear() + "," + " "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let d = new Date();
let daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
let monthlist = ["Jan","Feb","March","Apr ","May","June","July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
let amOrPm = (d.getHours() < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
let hour = (d.getHours() < 12) ? d.getHours() : d.getHours() - 12;
let date = daylist[d.getDay()]+','+ monthlist[d.getMonth()]+ " " + d.getDate()+','+' ' +d.getFullYear()+',' + ' ' + hour + ':' + d.getMinutes()+ ' ' + amOrPm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `date-fns` [package](https://date-fns.org/).
Manual date manipulation is not worth getting into.